# Getting newline before print statement - C

Tags: arrays, c, 2d

The runs stored by N batsmen of a cricket team is passed as the input to the program. The program must print the name of the batsman who scored the highest runs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int run[n],maxIndex=0; 
    char name[n][100];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%[^,],%d",name[i],&run[i]);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(run[i]>run[maxIndex])
             maxIndex=i;
    }
    printf("%s",name[maxIndex]);
    return 0;
```

}

```
Input:
    5
    BatsmanA,45
    BatsmanB,42
    BatsmanC,12
    BatsmanD,9
    BatsmanE,78
Output:
    BatsmanE
```

The issue is I'm getting a newline at first before the print statement. Like,

```
Output:

    BatsmanE
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some example input, together with the actual and expected output for that input.

Comment: As a hint about your problem: Most `scanf` formats skip leading white-space (like the newline added by the `Enter` key from previous `scanf` calls). However, the `%[]` format does *not* skip leading white-space. Also, you should *always* check what `scanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value). If you did, then you would have noticed that the first `scanf` call in the loop would have returned `1` instead of the expected `2`.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is I'm getting a newline at first before the print statement.

That is becasue `%[^,]` reads the prior line's left-over `'\n'` first.

---

`scanf("%d",&n);` reads the `"5"` and stores 5 into `n`.  `'\n'` remains in `stdin`.

`scanf("%[^,],%d",name[i],&run[i]);` reads the `"\nBatsmanA,45"` and stores `"\nBatsmanA"` into `name[0]`, then reads the `","`, then reads `"45"` and stores 45 into `run[0]`.

---

To read a line of user input, research `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to use scanf for string reading, you should make sure you can't get more characters than the string can handle. For that you can use [width](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) sub-specifier:

```
scanf("%99[^,],%d", name[i], &run[i]);
```

About the `'\n'` you got on the beginning of that string, that's because `"%[^,]"`
keeps it from the previous `scanf`, just add [*](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) that will read and discard that thing:

```
scanf("%*[\n]%99[^,],%d", name[i], &run[i]);
```

but as you can see, the format string becomes a lot less readable now...
Best thing would be if you just used `"%99s"` and rely on spaces instead of `','`:

```
scanf("%99s%d", name[i], &run[i]);
```

now you just separate the values with space in the input and get the same result:

```
Input:
    5
    BatsmanA 45
    BatsmanB 42
    BatsmanC 12
    BatsmanD 9
    BatsmanE 78
```

but at that point I'd personally prefer just separating the format into 2 *"scanfs"*:

```
scanf("%99s", name[i]);
scanf("%d", &run[i]);
```

And again, you will get the same result

Comment: But the constrain is to have comma separated inputs.

Comment: scanf("%99[^,],%d", name[i], &run[i]);   When I'm trying to use this no output is printed.

Comment: @Swetha Dharshini T that's weird, what compiler do you use? [it](https://onlinegdb.com/kqY-CMBnn) works for me...

Comment: `scanf("%99s", name[i]);` is not useful if the name contains a space like [Sachin Tendulkar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachin_Tendulkar).